# WordPress Forminator Form

Tags: wordpress, wpforms

Hello All WordPress Experts,

I wanted to ask how can we add the only year selection dropdown field in WordPress Forminator forms? Please guide if any one have idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use the below custom code as mu-plugin:
https://gist.github.com/wpmudev-sls/03cc9a37301f20c3199bc1437fe6ab6d

if you're not familiar with mu-plugins see here:https://wpmudev.com/docs/using-wordpress/installing-wordpress-plugins/#installing-mu-plugins

As an additional step, edit the label of the Datepicker fields whose dropdowns you want to hide. Just write @hide , as you can see in the image:

[image]